# IK rig handle stretch

Tags: rigging, constraints

So I followed a Youtube guide and I learned how to apply IK constraints and pole targets. After correctly setting it up, I tried posing it. Overall it works fine but whenever I move the bone out it's reach, the bone disconnects from the forearm and the mesh stretches like so:[image]

How do I make the IK rig handle bone separate from the model and not stretch the mesh, like auto IK?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix it would be to copy IK target, that you already have (It's R.Hand I presume), call it R.Hand_IK or something of that meaning. From what I see on the image it has no parent already - good.Disable Deform option for this bone (showed on the image below). Parent old R.Hand bone to arm bone (don't know how you called it, but it's the yellow one on the image). Remove IK constraint from the arm bone and add it to R.Hand bone. Then make R.Hand_IK target of this constraint.
[image]

Comment: I appreciate your initiative, Mzidare, however your suggestion did not solve my problem. You said this was the easiest way, do you have any more solutions?

Comment: It should work. What is your outcome?

Comment: The hand disappears into the forearm mesh. Perhaps we could consult to a Google Hangout to solve this problem?

Comment: send me a link to your file, I'll fix one hand and you will do the same with the other.

Comment: I posted a comment earlier this week but it didn't go through, sorry. I fixed the problem by parenting the foot bone to the shin and turning off location, rotation, etc.